# Jupyter Notebooks with ssh port forwarding crash due to package import

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, remote-server, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

In order to have interactive access to data on remote server, I usually use ssh port forwarding to run Jupyter Notebooks. I follow the standard procedure described here, https://confluence.uni-muenster.de/display/HPC/JupyterLab. Without going into the details this port forwarding corresponds to,

1. first submitting a slurm job to the remote server,
2. running Jupyter Notebook within that job,
3. creating an ssh tunnel to my local machine,
4. and finally directing a Browser on my local machine to that Jupyter Notebook.

This steps are implemented with a bash script under that link. Until now this has worked fine. But now I am trying to use a Python package called MDAnalysis and as soon I import this package to the notebook the kernel dies. But, when I login to the server and import MDAnalysis from Python, it seems to be fine.

Any idea why this is so ?